# podman ENTRYPOINT with multiple arguments

Tags: arguments, sh, program-entry-point, podman

I have a model which takes 3 arguments, (two files and a random number). The form of the call is:

```
modelExec -ind file1 -ainp file2 -sim x
```

where x is a random number.

I am trying to get this to run inside a container. I have a Docker file where the last two commands are

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh"]
CMD ["runModel.sh"]
```

if i hard code the value of x and save it in a shell script called (`newRun.sh`) like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
modelExec -ind file1 -ainp file2 -sim 10
```

and then run the container

```
podman run --mount "type=bind,src=/path_to_newRun,dst=/model_out" imageName newRun.sh
```

All runs just fine. I can then edit the shell script, change the number, and run again. This is obviously cumbersome. So i want to reconfigure this to pass the random number as an additional argument. But the first argument (the shell script) will require the second argument (random number)

I have tried something like this, where i hard code the value 1, then try to pass it another:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh"]
CMD ["runModel.sh","1"]
```

then

```
podman run --mount "type=bind,src=/path_to_newRun,dst=/model_out" imageName newRun.sh 5
```

In this case the `newRum.sh` script has the value of the random number omitted.

This obviously doesn't work. I am sure i am thinking about this all wrong. Anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

So i used the ideas from this [post](https://devopscube.com/run-scripts-docker-arguments/)

I reworked the shell script (runModel.sh) to take arguments and added it to the image, eg

```
#!/bin/bash
arg1=${1}
arg2=${2}
arg3=${3}
modelExec -ind $arg1 -ainp $arg2 -sim $arg3
```

My Dockerfile ended

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/runModel.sh"]
CMD ["datfile.dat","datafile.pin","1"]
```

And my run command became

```
podman run --mount "type=bind,src=/path_to_newRun,dst=/model_out" imageName file1 file2 5
```

All works great!